# Como colocar colunas bootstrap lado a lado com justify-content-around?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Como posso colocar a coluna amarela colada no lado da coluna roxa?

[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>clique para visualizar em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcRNE.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='estilo.css' type='text/css' />
  <title>Site Com Bootstrap</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row justify-content-around' style='height:500px; background-color: red;'>
      <div class='col-2' style='background-color: orange; height:100px;'>
        ...
      </div>

      <div class='col-2' style='background-color: yellow; height:100px;'>
        ...
      </div>

      <div class='col-2' style='background-color: purple; height:100px; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content: center;'>
        <div>algo</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: É só colocar a classe `ml-auto` na coluna amarela

Comment: Não funcionou corretamente, foi pro lado do roxo? sim, funcionou, mas o justify-content-around foi modificado, quando usa esses margins eles colocam as colunas colada nas margens. Por exemplo, se alguem tentar posicionar a coluna roxa no lado do amarelo, esses margins não funcionam.

Answer (score -2):

Amigo,

Faz uma estrutura assim:

```
Container
  Row
    Col
      Coluna Verde
    Col
      Container
        Row
          Col --> Aqui use o espaçamento que desejar
            Coluna Amarela
            Coluna Roxa
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: poxa, num tem algum comando tipo float:right?

Comment: float:right testei e não pegou ,gostaria de algo assim para eu colocar na coluna